# Check whether a specified XML element have certain name using JAVA

Tags: java, xml

Im working with JAVA and XML. Following is the XML file im working with:

```
<TestCase>
    <SelectedDataTableNames name="SearchData"> </SelectedDataTableNames>

    <Open page="hsbc"  ms="5000"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.Personal_Link"  />
    <Click object="hsbc.CreditCard_tab"  />
    <Call businessComponent="Global.Verify_Search">
       <Param name="HotelName_Param" value="@SearchData_link" />
    </Call>
    <CheckElementPresent object="hsbc.Img_Hotel_logo"  Identifire="Hotel_Name_PARAM:@SearchData_ResultHotelName"  fail="true"  customErrorMessage="Searched hotel name is not present in the page."  />
</TestCase>
```

And what my java code do so far is it gets all the elements under a specified parent(here "TestCase") and have to do different function according to different element name. What i found it difficult is how to check whether specified element contains the name. I couldnt check IF using "getElementsByTagName" as it will print true for all occurrence as there is that element. Here is the code and i have commented the place whether the check should occur.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("SearchPromotions.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Element docEle = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();

if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element ele = (Element) nl.item(i);

            if(//to check whther the current element is "Click"){
                System.out.println(ele);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use XSD validation. Have you try this?

Comment: No. Ill have look at it. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use `ele.getNodeName()` this will give you `Click`, `Open` i.e. the current node name then you can place a check in if